# What changes were made to Reloaded, EtM and Revolutions after Gloria Foster died?

Tags: the-matrix

Late Gloria Foster died of diabetes on September 29, 2001, during the shooting of Reloaded.
The Oracle was a central character and thus the role was kept, continued to be played by Mary Alice. The Matrix franchise tries to put an in-universe story around this change.

[image: Gloria Foster]

I cannot help but feel like the Oracle switching shells were only put in due to her death. Is there any proof pro or con this?

Some screen time in both Revolutions and Enter the Matrix deals with the issue and **it's unclear whether some of the scenes were added completely or changed heavily only for this issue.** If the whole shell thing were added later than it is more significant. The plot change may involve at least Rama-Kandra, Sati, Kamala, the Merovingian, Neo, and maybe many others (Niobe, Ghost, Seraph, Trinity, etc.)m potentially modifying the role of these characters, too.

How much impact the change in the role had on the plot?

Were there other scenes planned with the Oracle for Reloaded? What was the original plot of the franchise?

Answer (score 8):

I think that the shell change was only because Foster died. From what I remember, the change was only mentioned 2 or three times. Once when Neo met her right after her change and the Oracle said, "Do you recognize me?" or something. A second time when she said she needed to go into hiding, which could have happened without the actor change and a final time when Agent Smith found her and they mentioned her new body.

Everything else in the movie could have happened without the actor change, so I think that it wasn't a major issue.

Comment: EtM has some more scene time dedicated to "do you recognize me". But the thing is that I always felt that the whole Oracle changing shell story ark was put in because of Foster died.

Comment: edited the question to separate my assumption

Comment: I edited to add a clarification.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, without the shell change, what did Rama-Kandra give to the Merovingian as a payment for helping Sati? The Frenchman's services are exceptionally expensive.

Comment: Probably knowledge of the future.

Comment: But they may be further problems. "I am a trafficer of information, I know everything I can", and "Bring me the eyes of the Oracle and will give you back your savior" (M.). The Merovingian *already* has most of the information that exists. Knowledge on a (limited) range of future information won't benefit him greatly. He seems to seek either the death of his rival (Oracle) or her ability, thus becaming more powerful than her. "What does he want?" [...] "More power." The alternative is to ask for the eyes, but then what makes him later not just kill Trinity, Morpheus and Seraph right away?

Comment: I vaguely recall her change being in the terrible tie-in game *Enter the Matrix*, but it's been ...a decade or so.